# Neo4j Cypher two separate unwind loops in one query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am reading a big file into neo4j with the script below:

```
WITH $dict.rows as rows UNWIND rows as row
        WITH row WHERE  row.object CONTAINS 'wikidata'
          MERGE(e:Entity {wikidataId: replace(row.object,"http://www.wikidata.org/entity/","")})
          SET e.dbpediaUri = row.subject
WITH distinct $dict.rows as rows UNWIND rows as row
    MATCH(e:Entity) where e.dbpediaUri = row.subject
        WITH row, e
          CREATE(object:Property {value:row.object, type: "string"})
          WITH row,e,object
          CALL apoc.create.relationship(e, row.predicate, {source:"dbpedia", type:"uri"}, object) YIELD rel
          RETURN null
```

Here I want to first merge entities with the given wikidata id(Here I need the WITH with WHERE so that first I get the desired property), and in the second loop I want to add relationships to that entity.

I'm wondering if this code would end up with cartesian product? Will the second WITH ... UNWIND statement run inside the first one or not? If so, how can I achieve what I want to do in one query?

Comment: I found apoc.cypher.runMany to run separate commands in one query but it runs infinitely on prod env with lots of data even if I run a single CREATE command. It' weird. So I split these two loops and run in separate runs. That's what I got.

Comment: I would suggest you use Cypher subqueries feature. Also make sure to have correct indexes in place.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding your second unwind on **rows** will run inside the first one. I assume you want to prevent this. After `SET e.dbpediaUri = row.subject` you need to **close** the loop by using a proper aggregation function. Example in your case: `with collect(e) as entities`

Caution: in case `WITH row WHERE  row.object CONTAINS 'wikidata'` returns 0 records, the rest of the cypher query will NOT executed. The second unwind will never be reached. Therefore it is better to split your query in 2 different transactions
Best
Markus

Comment: Thanks, it seems that the only solution is to use apoc's runMany function to run multiple queries at the same time.